# Eclipse quick fix incomplete

Tags: java, eclipse

somehow the **eclipse quick fixes** are are sometimes **displayed incomplete** (see attached Screenshot) on my Kubuntu 13.04 System in Eclsipe 4.2. As you can see in the attached screenshot the Cange to suggestions and also the sugestions for package imports are displayed incomplete.

[image]

When I use the unity-Desktop they are displayed correctly.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

**The resizing-quick-tip work around is somehow not working for me. Furthermore Eclipse doesn't retain the size for new popups.**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried pressing F2 and then resizing? Worked for me, at least till eclipse restart.

Comment: Still an issue - if yes post a bug at eclipse and then post it here as an annswer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be related to the current [issue 407635](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=407635): "Size-related problems on Kubuntu", which can make the actual window size become smaller than its set minimum size.

Pending a fix, resizing the quick fix popup as mentioned by [Eugeny Loy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576549/eugeny-loy) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777665/eclipse-quick-fix-incomplete#comment24178143_16777665) is a workaround, since Eclipse will retain the new size for the next popup.